# Android dynamic language string

Tags: android

I've declared a string

```
 <string name="body_activity_welcome">Hello! <br />This is the welcome page. Only logged in users can see this page.</string>
```

But I want to personally greet the user

```
 <string name="body_activity_welcome">Hello {$username}! <br />This is the welcome page. Only logged in users can see this page.</string>
```

Is there a way to pass data to a language string when fetching it?

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_status_message);
    text.setText(R.string.body_activity_welcome); // somehow pass username to the string?
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29), and replace `{$username}` with `%1$s`.

Where

> %1: is the argument number
>
> $s: is the type

The first argument of getString is the resource id, then you have a varargs which is all data you want to pass to the string.

```
getString(R.string.body_activity_welcome, userName);
```

---

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_status_message);
text.setText(getString(R.string.body_activity_welcome, username)); //
```